# Magento Semicolon Breaking Query

Tags: mysql, magento

OK, surely there has to be a way to make this code work

```
->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'learn_about_us',
            '(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.fields,";",2),":",-1) FROM plugincompany_contactforms_entry p WHERE main_table.entity_id = p.entity_id)'
        );
```

for whatever reason that damn semicolon is breaking stuff. I want it in there because dealing with serialized data and don't want to process php side. But yea... if anyone has any insite in to how i can get this query to work please let me know.

Here is the error btw

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.fields,";",2),":",-1)
```

**Temporary Solution**

Not sure how to get around this but in this file

```
app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php
```

around line 1396 there is a protected variable

```
protected $_controlCharacters = array(
        ';',
        '--',
        '#',
        '/*',
        '*/',
    );
```

Notice the semicolon at the beginning, if i remove this then my query finally works... not quit sure if there is a way around this one =\

Comment: Use backslash to escape the semicolon?

Comment: Doesn't work that was my first thought

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your semicolon is breaking stuff. `addExpressionFieldToSelect()` takes 3 parameters, `$alias, $expression, $fields`, you're missing one of them.

Comment: If I change that section to `'(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.fields,":",2),":",-1) FROM plugincompany_contactforms_entry p WHERE main_table.entity_id = p.entity_id)'` then it works... i've tried using the 3rd parameter but i still get the same error which is `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.fields,";",2),":",-1) `